# CSRF Error event after adding CORS_TRUSTED_ORIGINS Django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to implement feature for changing password but when I make a put request from react frontend to django backend I am getting CSRF error. I am not getting such an error for other put/post requests.
Following are the code details:
settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    # ],
    # 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    #     'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    # ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'main.paginations.CustomPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 12
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

CORS_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
]
```

views.py

```
class ChangePasswordView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ChangePasswordSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    old_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = [ 'old_password', 'password', 'password2' ]

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Password fields did not match!'})
        return attrs

    def validate_old_password(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.check_password(value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'old_password': 'Old password provided is incorrect!'})
        return value

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        print(user)
        if user.pk != instance.pk:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"authorize": "You don't have permission to change password!",})
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

urls.py

```
...
    path('change_password/<int:pk>/', views.ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='auth_change_password'),
...
```

Frontend:

```
        const link = `${BASE_URL}${CHANGE_PASSWORD_URL}${customer_id}`;
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('old_password', oldPwdRef.current.value);
        formData.append('password', newPwdRef.current.value);
        formData.append('password2', confirmNewPwdRef.current.value);
        axios.put(link, formData, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            }}).then((response) => {
            console.log(`${TAG} response is ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(`${TAG} error: ${error}`);
        })
```

In django console logs I am seeing,

```
Forbidden (Origin checking failed - http://localhost:3000 does not match any trusted origins.): /api/change_password/2
[26/Oct/2023 06:09:11] "PUT /api/change_password/2 HTTP/1.1" 403 2569
```

and in Chrome console log I am seeing,

```
ChangePassword:  error: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
```

I tried with `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`. But it didn't work either.

Comment: What if you allow ALL does it work?